# Rotating/scaling around point of gesture

Tags: uwp, gesture

I want a user control to be moved/scaled/rotated by gestures, and I want the rotation and scaling to have its center point in the center of the gesture (e.g. when using two fingers to rotate, the point between the fingers should be the center of the rotation).

When I don't attempt to set a center point for rotation/scaling or set a static point, everything works as expected. When setting the CompositeTransform.CenterX/Y to the values of ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs.Position, the usercontrol will rotate with center points that get more wrong for every gesture, and occasionally speed away.

I'm using a CompositeTransform as the render transform of my user control, and I have hooked up to the ManipulationDelta-event like so:

```
private void UserControl_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //this.transform is my composite transform 
        //which is set to be the render transform of the user control
        this.transform.CenterX = e.Position.X;
        this.transform.CenterY = e.Position.Y;
        this.transform.ScaleX *= e.Delta.Scale;
        this.transform.ScaleY *= e.Delta.Scale;
        this.transform.Rotation += e.Delta.Rotation;
        this.transform.TranslateX += e.Delta.Translation.X;
        this.transform.TranslateY += e.Delta.Translation.Y;
    }
```

It seems that e.Position doesn't give me what I want, and unfortunately the documentation is very brief, only stating [*Gets the point from which the manipulation originated.*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.input.manipulationdeltaroutedeventargs#Windows_UI_Xaml_Input_ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs_Position) From my debug prints, it appears that both CompositeTransform.CenterX/Y and ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs.Position are in the coordinate system of the user control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that CompositeTransform can only handle *one* center point. Thus, when the center point changed, it changed retroactively for all previous transformations as well. The solution is to use a TransformGroup and create individual transformations with their own center points:

```
private void UserControl_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var localCoords = e.Position;
        var relativeTransform = this.TransformToVisual(this.Container);
        Point parentContainerCoords = relativeTransform.TransformPoint(localCoords);
        var center = parentContainerCoords;

        RotateTransform rotation = new RotateTransform();
        rotation.CenterX = center.X;
        rotation.CenterY = center.Y;
        rotation.Angle = e.Delta.Rotation;
        this.transformGroup.Children.Add(rotation);

        ScaleTransform scaling = new ScaleTransform();
        scaling.CenterX = center.X;
        scaling.CenterY = center.Y;
        scaling.ScaleX = e.Delta.Scale;
        scaling.ScaleY = e.Delta.Scale;
        this.transformGroup.Children.Add(scaling);

        TranslateTransform translation = new TranslateTransform();
        translation.X = e.Delta.Translation.X;
        translation.Y = e.Delta.Translation.Y;
        this.transformGroup.Children.Add(translation);
    }
```